# How to pass jwt token in retrofit interceptor

Tags: android, express, jwt, retrofit2

I am using jwt token for api routes protection in android I am creating Retrofit interceptor in order to pass token only one time for all the api endpoints.I am saving token in shared preferences but in retrofit singleton class how can I get that token and pass it in interceptor.

Below is my code:

**RetrofitClient.java**

```
public class RetrofitClient {

public static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getInstance(){

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

            Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                                 .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                                 .build();
            return chain.proceed(newRequest);
        }
    }).connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
      .readTimeout(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
      .writeTimeout(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
      .build();

    if(retrofit == null)
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                   .baseUrl("http://example.com")
                   .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()))
                   .client(okHttpClient)
                   .build();

   return retrofit;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use of your shareprerence into the method , I don't have java code but I am sharing you kotlin solution of your query , if it helps.

```
 var reqBuild = chain.request().newBuilder()

if(!sessionManager.getToken().isNullOrEmpty()){
    reqBuild (ApiConstant.header.Authorization, decideTokenBasedOnURL(chain.request().url.encodedPathSegments))
}
var request = reqBuild.build()
val response = chain.proceed(request)
return response
```